# can't install LWP::Parallel::UserAgent on Windows (Strawberry Perl)

Tags: perl, cpan

When I try to install LWP::Parallel::UserAgent using CPAN on Windows (Strawberry Perl v5.16.3), I get the below error. I think it might not be only me, because `reports MSOUTH/ParallelUserAgent-2.62.tgz` shows that it fails for most/all of the CPAN Testers on Windows.

Still, it seems like it should be an easy problem to solve. The problem is just that TAP::Formatter::Console can't be found. I actually have this module installed, but the installer is using a bad @INC. It is prepending `../` to absolute paths, like `../C:/berrybrew/5.16.3_64/perl/site/lib`. If it just stopped doing that, I think it might work. Any idea how to do that / otherwise fix this?

(EDIT: Alternatively, maybe the issue is that there isn't a `use TAP::Harness` in Test::Harness.pm. But I've installed plenty of other CPAN modules without issue.)

```
cpan> install LWP::Parallel::UserAgent
Database was generated on Tue, 15 May 2018 19:43:39 GMT
Running install for module 'LWP::Parallel::UserAgent'
Running make for M/MS/MSOUTH/ParallelUserAgent-2.62.tgz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/M/MS/MSOUTH/ParallelUserAgent-2.62.tgz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/M/MS/MSOUTH/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for C:\berrybrew\5.16.3_64\cpan\sources\authors\id\M\MS\MSOUTH\ParallelUserAgent-2.62.tgz ok
Scanning cache C:\berrybrew\5.16.3_64\cpan\build for sizes
............................................................................DONE

  CPAN.pm: Building M/MS/MSOUTH/ParallelUserAgent-2.62.tgz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for LWP::Parallel
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp lib/LWP/Parallel/Protocol/http.pm blib\lib\LWP\Parallel\Protocol\http.pm
cp lib/LWP/Parallel/Protocol/https.pm blib\lib\LWP\Parallel\Protocol\https.pm
cp lib/LWP/RobotPUA.pm blib\lib\LWP\RobotPUA.pm
cp lib/LWP/Parallel/UserAgent.pm blib\lib\LWP\Parallel\UserAgent.pm
cp lib/LWP/Parallel/Protocol/ftp.pm blib\lib\LWP\Parallel\Protocol\ftp.pm
cp lib/LWP/Parallel/Protocol/file.pm blib\lib\LWP\Parallel\Protocol\file.pm
cp lib/Bundle/ParallelUA.pm blib\lib\Bundle\ParallelUA.pm
cp lib/LWP/ParallelUA.pm blib\lib\LWP\ParallelUA.pm
cp lib/LWP/Parallel/Protocol.pm blib\lib\LWP\Parallel\Protocol.pm
cp lib/LWP/Parallel/RobotUA.pm blib\lib\LWP\Parallel\RobotUA.pm
cp lib/LWP/Parallel.pm blib\lib\LWP\Parallel.pm
  MSOUTH/ParallelUserAgent-2.62.tgz
  C:\berrybrew\5.16.3_64\c\bin\dmake.exe -- OK
Running make test
"C:\berrybrew\5.16.3_64\perl\bin\perl.exe" t/TEST
Can't load TAP::Formatter::Console: Can't locate TAP/Formatter/Console.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ../blib/lib ../blib/arch ../C:/berrybrew/5.16.3_64/perl/site/lib ../C:/berrybrew/5.16.3_64/perl/vendor/lib ../C:/berrybrew/5.16.3_64/perl/lib
../.) at (eval 30) line 2.
 at C:/berrybrew/5.16.3_64/perl/site/lib/Test/Harness.pm line 251.
dmake.exe:  Error code 130, while making 'test'
  MSOUTH/ParallelUserAgent-2.62.tgz
  C:\berrybrew\5.16.3_64\c\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports MSOUTH/ParallelUserAgent-2.62.tgz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'LWP::Parallel::UserAgent'.
Failed during this command:
 MSOUTH/ParallelUserAgent-2.62.tgz            : make_test NO
```